# How can I use Apache HTTP pooling connection manager with Spring WS?

Tags: spring-webclient, apache-httpclient-5.x

The connection seems to be pooled but not reused

Reuse of connections...

```
2022-11-24 21:08:50,934 [ReceiveDepth:1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection request: [route: {s}->https://services.mybank.nl:18290][total available: 4; route allocated: 4 of 4; total allocated: 4 of 4]
2022-11-24 21:08:50,934 [ReceiveDepth:1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-0: Close connection
2022-11-24 21:08:50,941 [ReceiveDepth:1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection leased: [id: 4][route: {s}->https://services.mybank.nl:18290][total available: 3; route allocated: 4 of 4; total allocated: 4 of 4]
2022-11-24 21:08:50,941 [ReceiveDepth:1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec      - Opening connection {s}->https://services.mybank.nl:18290
2022-11-24 21:08:50,941 [ReceiveDepth:1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator - Connecting to services.mybank.nl/10.239.166.11:18290
2022-11-24 21:08:50,969 [ReceiveDepth:1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator - Connection established 10.239.148.30:33114<->10.239.166.11:18290
2022-11-24 21:08:50,969 [ReceiveDepth:1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec      - Executing request POST /migrate HTTP/1.1
2022-11-24 21:08:50,969 [ReceiveDepth:1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec      - Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
2022-11-24 21:08:50,969 [ReceiveDepth:1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec      - Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
2022-11-24 21:08:50,983 [ReceiveDepth:1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec      - Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
2022-11-24 21:08:50,984 [ReceiveDepth:1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection [id: 4][route: {s}->https://services.mybank.nl:18290][state: CN=rc-uat3.rf.mybank.nl, OU=BSRC Groep ICT, O=Cooperatieve Mybank U.A., L=Utrecht, ST=Utrecht, C=NL] can be kept alive indefinitely
2022-11-24 21:08:50,984 [ReceiveDepth:1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-4: set socket timeout to 0
2022-11-24 21:08:50,984 [ReceiveDepth:1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection released: [id: 4][route: {s}->https://services.mybank.nl:18290][state: CN=rc-uat3.rf.mybank.nl, OU=BSRC Groep ICT, O=Cooperatieve Mybank U.A., L=Utrecht, ST=Utrecht, C=NL][total available: 4; route allocated: 4 of 4; total allocated: 4 of 4]
```

Comment: Could you apply some formatting to this mess? Please provide some details, debug information, settings, ...

Comment: That is the debug isn't it? What settings do you want?

Comment: Sorry am new to raising questions here. Not exactly sure what's required of me

Comment: There is the [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page worth a reading. Don't ask "Who can point.." because that is not your question. Show everything that is neccessary to reproduce the context and issue. Be specific about configuration but deduct sensitive information. You are working for a bank? Don't publish internal information, even hostnames, you set your job at risk and customer's finance. If you writing this programatically, provide the code to reproduce it.